# Dynamic content page, How to avoid covering (normal div and text) by absolute div

Tags: css, html

I have a "red" `div`, which I want to force under the "black" `div` and under the text in the footer And "red" `div` shoudld be over `div` with class `f_content`. See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npMgm/2/).

Where is my fault?

What should I change...?

Tricks with `z-index` give negative effect.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got, a solution:

```
    `f_content`
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;


    `image`
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;

   `cow_object`
   z-index: -1
```

[live solution](http://jsfiddle.net/npMgm/6/)

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, you do that with `z-index`. Just remember to always set the `position` to the element you want to set the index of.
See below, the red div is under the black one but above the blue footer:

<kbd>**[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/iwiqis/2)**</kbd>

Basically this is the only change needed in your code:

```
.wsp_box_data .image { 
  position: relative;
  z-index:  2;
}
```